# Build an array with a range of MAC addresses

Tags: php, arrays, range

I want to build an array which contains a full list of MAC addresses based on 3 variables: a prefix, a start, and an end.

Let's say I have `20:1E:50:3F:8A` as a prefix, `3E` as a start, and `43` as an end. This should generate the following array of MAC addresses:

```
20:1E:50:3F:8A:3E
20:1E:50:3F:8A:3F
20:1E:50:3F:8A:40
20:1E:50:3F:8A:41
20:1E:50:3F:8A:42
20:1E:50:3F:8A:43
```

I made a start, but it doesn't do the job just yet, and I can't get my head around it:

```
function generate($prefix, $start, $end){

    $start = str_split($start);
    $end = str_split($end);

    $start_first = $start[0];
    $start_second = $start[1];

    $end_first = $end[0];
    $end_second = $end[1];

    if(is_numeric($start_second)){
        $start_second_numeric = true;
    }
    else{
        $start_second_numeric = false;
    }

    if(is_numeric($end_second)){
        $end_second_numeric = true;
    }
    else{
        $end_second_numeric = false;
    }

    $mac_array = array();

    $range_first = range($start_first, $end_first);

    foreach($range_first as $first_character){

        if($start_second_numeric && $end_second_numeric || !$start_second_numeric && !$end_second_numeric){
            $range_second = range($start_second, $end_second);
        }
        elseif(!$start_second_numeric && $end_second_numeric){
            $range_second = range($start_second, "F");
            $range_third = range("0", $end_second);
        }
        elseif($start_second_numeric && !$end_second_numeric){
            $range_second = range($start_second, "9");
            $range_third = range("A", $end_second);
        }

        foreach($range_second as $second_character){
            $string = $prefix . ":" . $first_character . $second_character;
            array_push($mac_array, $string);
        }

        if(is_array($range_third)){
            foreach($range_third as $second_character){
                $string = $prefix . ":" . $first_character . $second_character;
                array_push($mac_array, $string);
            }
        }

    }

    return $mac_array;
}
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Why don't you just use `hexdec` and `dechex` to convert between numbers and the hex strings used in MAC addresses?

Comment: I wasn't actually aware of those 2 functions. And to be honest I didn't understand the way MAC addresses are built. This makes everything a lot easier and more understandable! Thank you!

Comment: You didn't know that MAC addresses are hex numbers? How do you end up with a project like this without knowing the basics, and not do some research? All you have to do is read the Wikipedia page, it explains this: _The standard (IEEE 802) format for printing MAC-48 addresses in human-friendly form is six groups of two hexadecimal digits, separated by hyphens (-) or colons (:),_

Comment: It's hardly worth calling it a project. But you're right. A little research can go far. I was looking at it from a silly angle and kept building based on that angle so to speak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running the range should be very easy, assuming you are using a 64bit capable PHP:

```
$mac_array = range(0x201E503F8A3E, 0x201E503F8A43);
foreach ($mac_array as $mac) {
    echo wordwrap(sprintf("%012X", $mac), 2, ":", true);
}
```

Now what is going on here?

The `range()` function creates an array containing integer numbers from the first to the second parameter (if you want to change the steps between, use the optional third parameter).

I use the hexadecimal writing of the numbers, and that's also the reason this is limited to 64bit PHP, because the MAC addresses are longer than 32 bits, 48 bits to be precise.

`foreach` iterates over that integer array.

Now for every integer, some formatting goes on. `sprintf()` is useful to format strings - in this case, I want it to print a hexadecimal number with at least 12 digits, and fill them with zeroes. That's what the string `"%012X"` does.

`wordwrap()` is a function that splits strings into smaller units with linking characters, by default splits a string into several lines of 75 characters or less, linking with newlines. I abuse it here a bit to split the hexadecimal number into units of 2 characters, and linking them with a colon.

All this is build into PHP already, and should be used. :)

Comment: Thank you for your solution and explaining. My PHP version is 64bit capable. This might be a stupid follow-up question: how would I be able to use the hexadecimal writing in combination with variables? Simply `0x . $mac` doesn't work.

Comment: I found the solution after some digging: `hexdec("\x00".$mac)`. Again thank you for your clean solution.

Answer (score -2):

This will help with the hex part:

```
public String[] range (String hexStart, String hexEnd)
{
    int start = Long.parseLong(hexStart, 16);
    int end = Long.parseLong(hexEnd, 16);
    String array[] = new String[end-start];

    for(int i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        array[i] = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(i), 16);
    }

    return array;
}
```

Comment: We are using PHP for this problem, not Java.

Comment: uhhhhh pseudocode i meant. yeah, java-like pseudocode...

Comment: Pseudocode means that it will not help.